# Converting a large string into a hash using split on delimiters

Tags: perl, hash

I am attempting to parse multiple values out of a dynamic, large string output from a Net::SSH2 command.  In order to do this, I believe I will need to convert the string into a hash.

Reading some, it seems that the split function is the way to create this dataset, using lists and multiple hashes

- edit
  Actual output from Data::Dumper and a regular print linked here:
  http://pastebin.com/7KagfWJV

If I run a 'print $data', I see something like this:

```
0 "Title1:\cJ Key:\cIValue\cJ\cI Key:\cIValue\cJ\ Key:\cIValue\cJTitle2:\cJ  Key:\cIValue\cJ\cI Key:\cIValue\cJ\cIValue\cJTitle3:\cJ Key:\cIValue\cJ\cI Key:\cIValue\cJ\cIValue\cJ"
```

Or in Data::Dumper format:

```
$VAR1 = 'Title1:
    aaa:    eee
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    aab:    fff
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    aac:    ggg
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    aad:    hhh
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
'Title2:
    baa:    iii
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    bab:    kkk
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    bac:    lll
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    bad:    mmm
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
'Title3:
    caa:    nnn
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    cab:    ooo
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    cac:    ppp
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
    cad:    qqq
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
            Key:    Value
';
```

I would expect, that to put this into a easily parsable format, I could split using the \cJ and \cI characters.  Any ideas?

- edit
  I have tried using YAML and YAML::Syck for the input stream but it would appear that YAML does not accept the data as it does not include a valid YAML header:

  YAML Error: Expected separator '---'
     Code: YAML_PARSE_ERR_NO_SEPARATOR
     Line: 2
     Document: 2
   at /Library/Perl/5.18/YAML/Loader.pm line 78.

Comment: In the first format, there is a value following a value, which doesn't happen in the second one. Can you post the same data in both the formats?

Comment: Value following a value not expected, see edit.

Comment: As [choroba has pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819817/converting-a-large-string-into-a-hash-using-split-on-delimiters#comment59307355_35819817), the two representations that you show are different data, so it's unclear what it really looks like. You also say nothing about what you want to do with your data structure once you have parsed the data into it so it's pretty much impossible to help you. It would help enormously if you showed some real data; as it stands it is unclear whether `Key` and `Value` are to be taken literally or are just placeholders

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's just a huge string and I was trying to simplify it.  Basically, I want to be able to assign any of the values in this data as a variable as needed, hence wanting a hash.  In the Data::Dumper output, for example being able to pull a "zone" and it's associated key->value pairs.    See real data:  http://pastebin.com/7KagfWJV

Comment: Does this output from SNMP? Maybe you need to use appropriate module from CPAN?

Comment: Not from SNMP and there are no CPAN modules for these devices to query something like a REST API sadly

Answer (score -1):

This data looks a lot like YAML. Maybe you could try using http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/YAML-1.15/lib/YAML.pod to parse it?

Comment: I tried loading and dumping using YAML and a few other implementations, Syck and Tiny.  YAML expects a header with a specific syntax it would appear - which this data set does not.  I don't believe it follows any standard format, just a big dumping of commands.  My mission here is to get this dataset into a format where I can parse it freely in something like YAML or JSON though.